# Authentication and authorization in SOAP based webservices Jive

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am working on SOAP webservices in Jive 4.5.5.0. I had written a code that has no authentication to it.

My sample program:

```
SuppressWarnings("serial")

@WebService(name="Helloworld",portName="HelloworldPort", serviceName = "Helloworld", targetNamespace="http://Helloworld.com/webservices")

@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use= SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle= SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)

public class Helloworld extends JiveActionSupport  {   

    public String sayHello(@WebParam(name="name")String name) {

        return "hello "+name;


    }

}
```

My spring.xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"

       xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"

       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"

       xsi:schemaLocation="

http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd

http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd

http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd

http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd"

       default-autowire="no">



    <!--  Alter the default mapping chains, switching formAuthenticationFilter with the federatedIdentityAuthFilter defined below.

          This definition uses the federated identity filter for normal app requests and Web Service requests, but leaves

          the form mechanism in place for admin and upgrade purposes. The desired behavior will vary depending on

          the application. -->

    <bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy">

        <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">

            <value>

                CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON

                PATTERN_TYPE_APACHE_ANT

                 /upgrade/**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, upgradeAuthenticationFilter, upgradeExceptionTranslationFilter, jiveAuthenticationTranslationFilter

                /post-upgrade/**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, postUpgradeAuthenticationFilter, postUpgradeExceptionTranslationFilter,jiveAuthenticationTranslationFilter

                /admin/**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, adminAuthenticationFilter, adminExceptionTranslationFilter,jiveAuthenticationTranslationFilter

                /rpc/xmlrpc=wsRequireSSLFilter, httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, basicAuthenticationFilter, wsExceptionTranslator, jiveAuthenticationTranslationFilter, wsAccessTypeCheckFilter

                /rpc/rest/**=wsRequireSSLFilter, httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, basicAuthenticationFilter, wsExceptionTranslator, jiveAuthenticationTranslationFilter, wsAccessTypeCheckFilter

                /rpc/soap/**=wsRequireSSLFilter, httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, basicAuthenticationFilter, jiveAuthenticationTranslationFilter

                /**=httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter, jiveAuthenticationTranslationFilter

            </value>

        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="hellworldbean" class="com.test.Helloworld">



        </bean>       



    <jaxws:endpoint id="helloworld" address="/soap/sayHelloworld">

        <jaxws:implementor>

            <ref bean="hellworldbean" />

        </jaxws:implementor>       

</jaxws:endpoint>





</beans>
```

I want to add authentication to it. Though basicAuthenticationFilter is there in /rpc/soap/** pattern, its not asking for authentication. In admin console settings, I have checked access to only specific users in web services.

This web service is working fine, giving the correct output. But It lacks authorization.

Can any one share some sample code to do authentication and authorization at client as well as and service.